# How to add multiple image view and each image view can do image picker?

Tags: ios, swift, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNyco.jpg)I'm making dating app.
so users need to update their images in profile.
In profile section,
there are small 3 image views.
and if they want to add image to each image views,
they should update each image view by UIimagepicker.
but I know I can only use only one function in UIImagepikerControllerDelegate protocol.

how can I do this?

below are my failed code

import UIKit

class RegisterPicture : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

```
@IBAction func pick1(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker1 = UIImagePickerController()

    picker1.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

    picker1.allowsEditing = true

    picker1.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(picker1, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func pick2(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker2 = UIImagePickerController()

    picker2.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

    picker2.allowsEditing = true

    picker2.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(picker2, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func pick3(sender: AnyObject) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

    picker.allowsEditing = true

    picker.delegate = self

    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet var picture1: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var picture2: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var picture3: UIImageView!

func imagePickerController(picker1: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    picker1.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion : nil)


}

func imagePickerController(picker2: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    picker2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion : nil)
    self.picture2.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}

func imagePickerController(picker3: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    picker3.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion : nil)
    self.picture3.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker2: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker2.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker3: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker3.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion:nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood what you need but what I suggest is that those UIImageViews could be in a collection view.

By doing that, the only delegate for the image picker would be the view controller that holds the collection view of the images and you would just update the selected cell with the picked image

Answer (score 0):

You give the tag to each imageView when you are creating imageView and
 inside this method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController )picker  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary )info
```

with the help of if else condition you can use each imageView separately.

Comment: you have to use this function which i have mention without this you cannot do the feature you want as far as i know, use tag with each imageview

Answer (score 0):

You can create this as a new project to not deal with assigned actions - or you can clear the actions and outlets in your view and recreate according to the new code.

Create 3 UIImageViews, picture1, picture2, picture3. Link the outlets in the code.

Create a UIToolbar with 3 UIBarButtonItems. Set bar button item tags to be 1,2,3 corresponding to the picture1, picture2, picture3 image views.

Connect outlets for image views (picture1,2,3)

Connect picker action to ALL THREE bar button items. Those will be using the same action, no need to repeat code, difference will be detected by the sender button's tag.

Follow the code, it will explain itself. It just decides which UIImageView will be the "active" one during the image pick according to the clicked bar button then delegate will use that image view.

Let us know if doesn't make sense.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBAction func picker(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum

    switch sender.tag {
    case 2:
        self.imageView = picture2
    case 3:
        self.imageView = picture3
    default:
        self.imageView = picture1
    }


    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBOutlet weak var picture1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var picture2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var picture3: UIImageView!

var imageView: UIImageView!
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imagePicker.delegate = self

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

EDIT: Here is the sample project I just uploaded:
https://github.com/smozgur/Multiple-Image-Picker